# How to code alternative to mysql_field_name in MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I replace mysql_field_name using MYSQLi since that has depreciated in PHP 7? I saw in the manual to use mysqli_fetch_field_direct but I don't understand how to incorporate that.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
    {
        $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
            stripslashes(mysql_field_name($result, $i))) . $csv_enclosed;
        $schema_insert .= $l;
        $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
    } // end for
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to figure out and it's working now. Thanks for reading.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_cnt; $i++)
{       
    $l = $csv_enclosed . str_replace($csv_enclosed, $csv_escaped . $csv_enclosed,
        mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name) . $csv_enclosed;

    $schema_insert .= $l;
    $schema_insert .= $csv_separator;
} // end for
```